# GCP cloud monitoring self-defined metric (memory utilization)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, operation, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to create a metric of 'memory usage in percentage' for cloud functions.
However, the default metric only support `metric 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/function/user_memory_bytes'`.

I need to divide the value by the memory limit of my cloud function (metadata `metric.memory`).
My goal is to keep track of the percentage if it exceeds 80% threshold, for example. Then it is time to consider increasing the memory limit or migrate to other computing solutions.

Currently, I try to achieve my goal with pure MQL query.
Maybe I should create another cloud function, GET metric values via monitoring API, and then POST it after calculation?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

#### [update-1]

Currently, the best I can do is the MQL below:

```
fetch cloud_function
| 
{
metric 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/function/user_memory_bytes'
}
| group_by [resource.function_name, metric.memory], mean(val())
| every 15m
```

and the output is here:
[image]

The last step is "how can I get the value of 'Value'/'metric.memory'"?

Please help.

Comment: You can go through the following links for the required information. 1)https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#retrieving-metrics
2)https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/metrics

Answer (score 0):

If the limit is available as a metric, you can compute the ratio using MQL:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples#qlx-ratios

If not, you could simply hard-code the limit in your MQL calculation - this is probably the simplest, though painful to maintain, approach.  If you have IaC automation in place that manages both the function and this alerting policy, you could manage that through the automation, however.